# com.squareup.okhttp3 (3.14.0) causes Exception on Android 7?

Tags: java, android, exception, okhttp, logcat

Having this code work fine on Android 9+ but produces Exception on Samsung Galaxy S6 / Android 7:

myCode.java:

```
...
// getOkHttp3Response
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient; //com.squareup.okhttp3.okHttp.3.14.0
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
...
private String getRouteOkHttp3Response(String _uri) {
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    String strResp = "";
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(_uri).build();
        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }
        strResp = response.body().string();
        if (!strResp.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            return strResp;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "getRouteOkHttp3Response Exception: " + e.getMessage() );
        return "";
    }
};
```

Android Studio logCat:

```
2020-06-23 11:30:41.260 15493-15493/? I/System.out: getRouteOkHttp3Response Exception: null
```

What could cause the Exception, is it related to the API version?

According to: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.0
It seems to be supported by Android 4.1.1.4

Edit:
Build version (from build.gradle)

```
ext {
   buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
   minSdkVersion = 16
   compileSdkVersion = 28
   targetSdkVersion = 28
}
```

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/security/ - 3.14.x requires Android 5+, which should be fine for your original question but doesn't match mvnrepository.  You should either bump minSdkVersion to 21, or revert to OkHttp 3.12.12.